# Flood filling without using function (Matlab)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-segmentation, flood-fill, binary-image

Im working on my project where one of the operations that i needed to do first is **flood filling** before achieving the outcome. I am aware that there are available function such as bwmorph or imfill to flood fill the black pixels of my image but im required to do it without any functions. Please do help !

Original Image:

[image]

Outcome Image:

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Answer (score 0):

1. Black connected component labeling (union-find algorithm).
2. Delete all the components that do not touch the borders.